# I need to hide one thumbnail, not all

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have 5 thumbnails and want to hide or not display one of them on mobile devices. Is it possible to just hide one thumbnail using css media queries?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible. Do you have code to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to define a class and put it inside a media query.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .hide-mobile{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and assign that class to the image you want to hide.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes its very easy to do something like this, I would suggest doing a few css courses because this is a very simple thing to do there are many ways you can go about doing this below is one example

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <img src="thumbnail1" class="thumb1">
    <img src="thumbnail2" class="thumb2">
    <img src="thumbnail3" class="thumb3">
    <img src="thumbnail4" class="thumb4">
    <img src="thumbnail5" class="thumb5">
</div>
```

make sure the element you are trying to hide has its own class as shown above and then all you need to do is hide it at your breakpoints

CSS

```
@media (max-width: "your width px"){
     .thumb5{
          display: none;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Run the code snippet, expand it to full size and then change the browser size to smaller than `400px`.

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .img3 {display:none;}
}
```

```html
<img class="img1" src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
<img class="img2" src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
<img class="img3" src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
<img class="img4" src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
<img class="img5" src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!